# How can I mount a one gang box to a pipe?

Tags: electrical, code-compliance

I would like to mount a single gang box to a pipe and stay code compliant. I have a 1-1/2" pipe (but that can be changed), and I would like to have an outlet on the side of the pipe for mounting a projector on the pipe and plugging it in right at the pipe instead of at the wall.

Or, even better, is there a product that I can mount to a pipe that has a box integrated into it?

Comment: When you say pipe - you mean a plumbing pipe?

Comment: Yeah it makes a difference what's *in* the pipe. If you say it is a Sch 40 PVC plumbing vent pipe you are going to get different answers than if you say it is a titanium pipe carrying superheated steam which you have purchased as surplus parts from decommissioned Russian submarines bought off the dark web and which is now set up in your basement to tap into a geothermal hot spot under your house.

Comment: It's not pvc, but it's standard plumbing pipe. Iron, probably.

Answer (score 2):

*This question brought to you by Home Depot and their lousy selection.*

I do a ton of EMT conduit. Hanging EMT or junction boxes off pipes is *completely routine*.

Just from [one page on Grainger](https://www.grainger.com/category/pipe-hangers-and-clamps/pipe-and-tubing-accessories/pipe-tubing-and-fittings/plumbing/ecatalog/N-qv7):

[image]
[image]
[image]

If the pipe clamps are blind threaded, like two of these are, take care to select sizes that fit the existing holes in your junction boxes, typically 10-32 or 10-24 is safe, sometimes 1/4-20 will work.  And select machine screws short enough they don't bottom out and break the clamp.

Your friendly neighborhood electrical supply house will have some of these, and other options, in stock.

Don't use the hole in your junction box that is tapped 10-32, that is for a ground screw.

I  have also seen people drill and tap holes directly into steel poles, then then simply use machine screws to attach the box.  Obviously the pipe contains no fluid.

Comment: Would a product like this meet code? http://www.electricbargainstores.com/product-p/RAB-MPAB.htm?gclid=CjwKCAjwg_fZBRAoEiwAppvp-ayc82V_gs_F3dH_c4Ky1kMNuKNJ5fY5ToPLbzy3M2nNJG0VInIDMRoCVdoQAvD_BwE

Comment: @JohnBeavers It's made for that purpose. The only remaining question is if it's UL listed for that purpose.  (Or CSA, TUV or other testing lab). CE is not a testing lab.